# RewriteRule and query string with dash

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want to redirect https://example.com?id=-aA09 to https://example.com/#/app/site/-aA-09. I have the following RewriteCond and RewriteRule, which does not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/#/app/site/%1? [R=301,NE,L]
```

If I change the RewriteCond to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([a-z]+)$
```

it works for redirecting when id = abc but obviously not for id = -aA-09. How do I match the "-" (dash) as well?

I've also tried the following which does not work either

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)$
```

**EDIT**

The first example seems to work for id = -KWIwMccN6FcVhEHs-Fz but not for id = -KvmFLPxxb2w07cNa1cH

Comment: Have you tried `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+`?

Comment: Leading / trailing dashes do not need to be escaped in a character class - with that in mind, are you showing us your full htaccess - this test suggests what you had originally works: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=b60826d3-702a-5885-ae56-4237bb55bff1

Comment: I am not using htaccess, the rewrite is placed in the directly in my <VirtualHost>. I am running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS